# Grouped bar chart with multiple levels of grouping in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I would like to make a grouped bar chart with multiple levels of grouping as shown below -

[image]

I would like to have the character 'AR' in the graph. The data for the graph is attached with the post.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4

AR                      1
AR      1100    0.5     2
AR      1100    1       3
5       1000    0.5     4
5       1000    1       5
5       1050    0.5     4
5       1050    1       5
5       1100    0.5     4
5       1100    1       5
15      1000    0.5     4
15      1000    1       5
15      1050    0.5     4
15      1050    1       5
15      1100    0.5     4
15      1100    1       5
```

Data from column 1 to 3 should be used for grouping on the X-Axis and the data on column 4 to be used for the height of the bars.

Is it possible to add prefixes or suffixes to the grouping like 0.5h or 1000 C or 5% ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the absence of any other answer, I'll post my attempt (done in Octave). It's not perfect, but it's the best I could do. I put your data in a `*.csv` file:

[image]

I had to create one `XTickLabel` per bar. Also, because `csvread` only imports numerical data, I had to manually adjust the `XTickLabel` for the first 3 bars. There may be a better and cleverer way to do this:

```
data = csvread('data.csv');
data_str = cell(size(data,1),1);  

for k=1:size(data,1)
  if k<=3
    data_str{k} = sprintf([num2str(data(k,3)) '\n' num2str(data(k,2)) '\nAR']);
  else
    data_str{k} = sprintf([num2str(data(k,3)) '\n' num2str(data(k,2)) '\n' num2str(data(k,1))]);
  end
end
data_str{1} = sprintf(['' '\n' '' '\nAR']);

figure 
hold on
h1 = bar(1:2:size(data,1),data(1:2:end,4));
set(h1,'FaceColor','g','BarWidth',0.4)
legend('D','Location','NorthEast')
h2 = bar(2:2:size(data,1),data(2:2:end,4));
set(h2,'FaceColor','b','BarWidth',0.4)
set(gca,'XTick',1:15)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',data_str)
xlim([0 size(data,1)+1])
ylim([0 max(data(:,4))+1])
ylabel('D')
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thankx for the quick reply.

Comment: @VijayBharadwajJ Can you explain exactly what didn't work? The code is bog-standard MATLAB/Octave code, and should work equally well in both products.

Comment: This is the result I'm getting. 

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/auu7C.jpg

I'm not sure how to add images to my comment. I'm guessing that the labeling is happening in a column major order(inherent in MATLAB, I think) and stops after 15 entries, i.e the number of bars in total.

Comment: OK, well then change `set(gca,'XTickLabel',data_str)` to `set(gca,'XTickLabel',data_str')`. Also, if you are using my code, you shouldn't see the `data1` entry in your legend, as the call to `legend` is done only for the first half of the bars (the green ones).

Comment: I'm not sure that I have created that same data.csv file that you have created.  Here is the screen-shot of my data.csv file - [1]  I made the change and it did not effect in any way, the labels are still the same and data1 is still present in the legend.  I tried the code(original and with the transpose) in octave. Both give the same result as the one you have shown.  [1] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wswS9.png

Comment: @VijayBharadwajJ I have added a screenshot of the CSV file containing the data, it is the same data as in your question.

Comment: Yes, I checked with that also. The output you got is observed only in Octave and not in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = [1 2 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5];

figure

% hold on

h = bar(y);

xTick = 1:15;

set(gca,'xtick',xTick);

yTick = get(gca,'ytick');

set(gca,'xticklabel',[])

xTickLabel = {{'-\newline';'-';'AR'},{'0.5h';'1100 C';'AR'},{'1h';'1100 C';'AR'},{'0.5h'; '1000C' ;'5%'},{'1h'; '1000C';'5%'},{'0.5h'; '1050C'; '5%'},{'1h'; '1050C'; '5%'},{'0.5h'; '1100C'; '5%'},{'1h'; '1100C'; '5%'},{'0.5h'; '1000C'; '15%'},{'1h'; '1000C'; '15%'},{'0.5h'; '1050C'; '15%'},{'1h'; '1050C'; '15%'},{'0.5h'; '1100C'; '15%'},{'1h'; '1100C'; '15%'}};

for k = 1:length(xTick)

    text(xTick(k),yTick(1)-0.06*(yTick(end)-yTick(1)),xTickLabel{k},'HorizontalAlignment','center')

end
```

Finally, this is what I have narrowed down to and the result is this - 
[image]